# UICollectionView inside UITableView incorrect rows in sections

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a `UITableView` in the Groups (Sectioned) mode. Each section of the table contains about 5 cells.
Each cell of the table consists of one `UILabel` and one `UICollectionView`. `UICollectionView` will contain a set of simple items with a horizontal scrolling.

**So, I have something like a Grid View and it looks in Storyboard like:**
[image]

**In the Simulator it looks like:**
[image]

**The problems that I can't understand:**

When I scroll any of the rows horizontally - some another row (that may be in the same or some another section) can synchronously scrolls with the first one, looks like they have some connection with each other or it's the same `UICollectionView`!

How can I use different `UICollectionView` in each `UITableViewCell` or break that "strange connection"?

**My code (Header):**

```
@interface ipAthleteHistoryTableViewController : UIViewController <UICollectionViewDataSource, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *datesRangeFromPeer;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *datesRangeToPeer;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *history;

- (IBAction)datesRangeFromPeerEditingExited:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)datesRangeFromPeerSet:(id)sender;

- (IBAction)datesRangeToPeerEditingExited:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)datesRangeToPeerSet:(id)sender;

- (IBAction)todaySpeedButtonPressed:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)weekSpeedButtonPressed:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)monthSpeedButtonPressed:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)quarterSpeedButtonPressed:(id)sender;

@end
```

**Implementation:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    _dumbNumberOfItems = 24;
    _dumbNumberOfItems2 = 5;

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return _dumbNumberOfItems2;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return _dumbNumberOfItems;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 5;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"12.09.2014:%ld", (long)section];
}

- (UITableView *)findParentTableView:(UITableViewCell *)tableCellView
{
    return (UITableView *)[ipNavigationHelper findParentViewOfClass:[UITableView class]
                                                    ofChildView:tableCellView];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{       
    ipAthleteHistoryTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:athleteHistoryChart_ExcerciseTrialsCell forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [[cell excerciseTitle] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Title %li:%li; %ld", [indexPath section], (long)[indexPath row], (long)[cell excerciseTrials]]];
    [[cell excerciseTrials] reloadData];

    return cell;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ipAthleteHistoryExcerciseTrialCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:athleteHistoryChart_TrialCell
                                                                                     forIndexPath:indexPath];
    ipAthleteHistoryTableCell *upCell = [self findParentTableCell:collectionView];

    [[cell actualTrial] setText:[ipNumeralsConverter convertToLatinArabNumber:[indexPath row]]];
    [[cell actualRepeats] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", [[[self findParentTableView:upCell] indexPathForCell:upCell] section]]];
    [[cell targetRepeats] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", [[[self findParentTableView:upCell] indexPathForCell:upCell] row]]];
    [[cell workWeight] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", [indexPath row]*10]];

    return cell;
}
```

All the initial work (like IDs registration, cells prototyping, etc.) is done using Storyboard.

Comment: The problem could be in findParentTableCell, but I can't see that code. Traversing view hierarchy is always risky as things can change between versions and it just isn't very nice design. If I were you, I would make a data model class and make this class implement the collection view delegate, then in cellForRowAtIndexPath you can simply assign the delegate of the cell's collection view to the appropriate data model object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is probably related to the fact that UITableViewCells get reused. So when you scroll and see a new cell, it really is just one of the cells that went away. To deal with your issues, you'll need to make sure the cell is properly initialized in cellForRowAtIndexPath and make sure you override any previous data you had in there.

Comment: Yes, it seems you are right, but I'm not sure how to "reset" UICollecionView state properly. For example, how to stop its scrolling (when I scroll UICollectionView of A-TableViewCell and while it's moving I really can see that some C-TableViewCell is moving too), etc...

Comment: You might try calling `[[cell excerciseTrials] setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:NO]` after calling reload data.

Comment: A problem will be that whenever you scroll, the collection view's scroll will always reset to the beginning. To avoid this you could keep track the current content offset for each collection view and set that instead of CGPointZero in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, finally I've decided to escape from the cells reusing functionality by creating unique Cell IDs and creating it "on-the-fly" without Storyboard prototyping. It looks fine now.

The code is standard:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%ld-%ld",
                                             athleteHistoryTable_ExcerciseTrialsCell,
                                             (long)[indexPath section],
                                             (long)[indexPath row]];
    ipAthleteHistoryTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[ipAthleteHistoryTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                            reuseIdentifier:cellId];

        [[cell excerciseTrials] registerClass:[ipAthleteHistoryExcerciseTrialCell class]
               forCellWithReuseIdentifier:athleteHistoryTable_TrialCell];

        [[cell excerciseTrials] setDataSource:self];
    }

    [[cell excerciseTitle] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Excercise Title %li:%li; %ld",
                                                         [indexPath section],
                                                         (long)[indexPath row],
                                                         (long)[cell excerciseTrials]]];

    [[cell excerciseTrials] reloadData];

    return cell;
}
```